# What if you want to nest one anchore link inside another?

Tags: html

### HTML:

```
<a href="#link1">link one text, 
   <a href="link2">link two text</a>
link1 on continue.</a>
```

### Browser parser reads it as:

```
<a href="#link1">link one text,</a>
   <a href="link2">link two text</a>
link1 on continue.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Found one solution:

### HTML:

```
<a href="#link1">link one text, 
   <object><a href="link2">link two text</a></object>
link1 on continue.</a>
```

### Browser parser reads it as:

```
<a href="#link1">link one text,</a>
<a href="link2">link two text</a>
<a href="#link1">link1 on continue.</a>
```

**Fiddle**
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k6ez601b/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with plain html. It would also, I think, be incredibly confusing to the user. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have update the answer. Added demo link. You can have a look, its working fine.